# What is the range of the LEGO Powered Up remote control system?

Tags: powered-up

I'm curious how far I will be able get away from my creation before the remote and/or smart device is no longer able to control it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mileage may vary, but [according to LEGO](https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/city/faq-train), the range is about **10m (33ft) in open air**.

> The Bluetooth signal distance is usually around 10 meters/33 feet in an open area, but it can vary, depending on a few things: Low batteries in the remote control, and obstacles – concrete walls, for example – may decrease the signal distance. Try to remove obstacles, or find another place to play with your train, if it seems like the distance is shorter than expected.